# media URL картинка не отображается

Tags: python, django

Не отображаются картинки через URL/
структура папок project/ static, media, ...

сеттингс:

```
STATIC_URL = '/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    '/home/s/strweru/htdocs/static',
    ]
```

html:

```
<li><a href="/cakes/some/{{ tort.id }}/"><img width="120" height="120" src="{{ tort.tort_img1.url }}"></a></li>
```

в чем я не прав?

Comment: `STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = {
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
}`

Comment: `MEDIA_URL = '/media'    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")`

Comment: и не забудьте `{% load staticfiles %}` в шаблоне